# Delphi - convert two exe's into one service?

Tags: delphi, service, exe

I have got two different executables written in Delphi 6.  I am in the process of converting these into windows services.  I have already converted one and it's working great.

Is it possible to pull the second Delphi App into this new Service too, perhaps running as its own thread?  Or must I convert them each into their own service.

I basically want to run both apps in just one service.

Also, are there any Windows Vista/7 issues I need to be aware of?  Aside from the obvious of being logged in as administrator to install the service(s).

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2 EXEs 1 Service :
It depends on how your application run.  One Delphi Service Application and have multiple TService descendent.  If you can make 2 Service Module for your 2 application, you can well put them in 1 Service application.

In practice, you can add a Service Application, which will automatically add 1 service to process your 1st application.  Then you can add another service to process the work for your 2nd application.

Regarding Window 7 (and Vista too), these newer OS separate service running in session 0 (like another internal desktop other than those used by logged in users).  Therefore, any user interface in a service (like pop-up forms, tray icons, etc) is generally not visible to the users.

If your applications do have user interface, you may also take reference for this post :
[Converting a Delphi application to run as a service - is it necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102632/converting-a-delphi-application-to-run-as-a-service-is-it-necessary)