# Switching between standalone EXE and windows service

Tags: delphi, windows-services

I have written an application that on timer sends logs by mail. This application has a minimalistic user interface and once a config file is there it can start without the need of an interaction with the user.

Currently it is a VCL Forms application, but in some cases it would be good to have a service (in this way when running on a server there is no need to open a user session just to run the application).

What do you suggest for having both the worlds? In some simple scenario (smal organization, with just 3 pcs and no IT manager) a "non service" is good because it is easier to understand and to use, but in bigger organization the lack of service is a problem.

Is it possible to have a service and non service at the same time? How to achieve this? I don't want to make the deployment more complex, what I have in mind is some command line switch: when run with command line paramenters it can be a service, if not a normal app... How to do this?).

Comment: One of my answers to a different question gives code that does what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594152

Comment: possible duplicate of [A standalone Delphi application that can also be installed as windows service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387383/a-standalone-delphi-application-that-can-also-be-installed-as-windows-service)

Answer (score 6):

OK...the best way is to develop 'service' and 'non service' application in the same project.
Like explained here : [A standalone Delphi application that can also be installed as windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387383/a-standalone-delphi-application-that-can-also-be-installed-as-windows-service).
So you may use the same application as service or as stand alone application.

If you want to have both on the same PC, it is more complicated : you have to add, in the stand alone application, the functions :

- Verifiy if the service is running and active.
- If the service is
  running and active, you have to dialog with it instead of runing the
  stand alone process.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a control panel applet that sets uf the config needed for your application and then convert your app into a service. Your control panel applet could also start, stop and restart the service, etc.

You now have the best of both worlds.

John

Comment: Do control panel applets still exist? I thought they kind of died out after Vista. I also struggle to see quite how a control panel applet solves anything. Perhaps I'm just being slow today.

Comment: If you have to make a control panel applet, you would need Delphi XE2, and to build a 32 and 64 bit control panel applet.

Comment: @WarrenP...32 bit CP applets will run on a 64 bit system/OS, A 32 bit service will also run on a 64 bit system/OS.

Comment: @David Hefferman... My Win 7 is laoded with Control Panel Applets! Unless your version of Cp Applet is different than mine.

Comment: @David... How a CP Applet solves his problem... And, "This application has a minimalistic user interface and once a config file is there it can start without the need of an interaction with the user." Seems perfect to me for a CP Appalet to do just a config. Maybe I am slow. Understand that this is Just my humble opinion and he was seeking advice. I have done it and have a 32 bit CP and service on Win server 2208 RS 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is have a separate project that is for development use only. I just create a form, then that creates the service and makes the calls expected.

```
  unit fTestHarness;

  interface

  uses
     uMyServiceModule,
    Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms;

  type
    TfrmCentralTest = class(TForm)
      Label1: TLabel;
      Label2: TLabel;
      procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
      procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    private
      { Private declarations }
    public
      { Public declarations }
    end;

  var
    frmTest: TfrmTest;

  implementation

  {$R *.dfm}

  procedure TfrmCentralTest.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  var
     bStarted : boolean;
  begin
     bStarted := False;
     MyService := TMyService.Create(self);
     MyService.ServiceStart(nil, bStarted);
  end;

  procedure TfrmCentralTest.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  var
     bStopped : boolean;
  begin
     MyService.ServiceStop(nil, bStopped);
  end;

  end.
```